# Open Modal Dialog on Title click in list?

Tags: list, javascript, sharepoint-online, modal-dialog

I have a Sharepoint-hosted app. When you click on "No Title" in a list you get a new window where the items is being showed. What I want is, when user click on "No Title" in the list it should pop up a dialog box that shows all items.

I'm using javascript!

[image]

**Jordan:**

I've tried now but didnt get it to work should the dialog come up when you press on the "No Title" or am i doing somthing wrong?

```
var clientContext, hostweburl, parentContext, parentWeb, list, listId, itemIds;

clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
listId = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListId"));
itemIds = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPListItemId"))
parentContext = new SP.AppContextSite(clientContext, hostweburl);
parentWeb = parentContext.get_web();
list = parentWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("CoromaticIFU");


$(document).ready(function () {
$("#tabs").tabs();
$(document).tooltip();
$('#GEN_4').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
$('#save').click(setItems);


//Getting id and title variables to pass into the Edit form
var funString = "../Lists/CoromaticIFU/DispForm.aspx?ID=";
$("a[id*='item']").click(function(){ 
    var number = $(this).attr("name");
    var title = $(this).text();
    showDialogGetID(funString, number, title); return false;}); 
});


function showDialogGetID (url, id, title) {
url = url + id;

if (typeof url != "string")
    throw new Error.argument("url", "Expected a string.");

var options = {};
options.title = title;
options.url = url;

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}  




function setItems() {
var listCreationInformation = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation(), listItem = list.addItem(listCreationInformation);

listItem.set_item('GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment', $('#GEN_1').val());
listItem.set_item('GEN_1_Sum_Scope_Assigment_D', $('#GEN_1_D').val());
listItem.set_item('GEN_2_CRMname', $('#GEN_2').val());
listItem.set_item('GEN_2_CRMname_D', $('#GEN_2_D').val());
listItem.update();

clientContext.load(listItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (success) { alert("Din sparning lyckades!"); }, function (sender, args) { alert('Error:' + args.get_message()); });   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Launch forms in a dialog?. Check Yes here.

**Update**

The corresponding property which needs to be set in code is `NavigateForFormsPages`. Here is a sample schema.xaml file of a List Definition containing this attribute:

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="ClientAnnouncementsListDef" Url="Lists/ClientAnnouncementsListDef" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" NavigateForFormsPages="FALSE">
  <MetaData>
    ....
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

Comment: Ok thanks but how can i do it with code becuse when you get this dialog with all items i want my own survey form to come up and show all the items in textboxes you know how to do that?

Comment: Where in my app.js do i put this line of code to get to work?

Comment: Can you share how you are creating the list?

Comment: Trough site content -> add an app -> custom list

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question properly. If you want to simply open the items in popup and you are creating a list manually through UI, then you can set the property as I described in the answer

Comment: ok i will try again
1. I have a sharepoint-hosted app with a survey from with textboxea and radiobuttons.
2. When the users have answerd all questions they press save and the anwsers is saved to list.
3. When they then want to read theirs anwers in the list I want it to open in a dialog box with the same survey form and all the answers in the textboxes

Comment: This requirement is different than what you mentioned in the original question. You should perhaps open a new question for this.

Comment: ok Thansk sry for the confusen

Answer (score 0):

I use this launch a modal dialog.  You can create any edit form or display form to point this to.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  //Getting id and title variables to pass into the Edit form
  var funString = "../Lists/ListName/EditForm.aspx?ID=";
  $("a[id*='item']").click(function(){ 
    var number = $(this).attr("name");
    var title = $(this).text();
    showDialogGetID(funString, number, title); return false;}); 
});

//function used for EditForm
function showDialogGetID (url, id, title) {
  url = url + id;

  if (typeof url != "string")
    throw new Error.argument("url", "Expected a string.");

  var options = {};
  options.title = title;
  options.url = url;

  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

I use data views to display the list which allows me to place my ID in the name property and pull it from here when I run my function.

Noticed you want to view all items instead of display for individual.  I haven't tested it, but you could try putting the list URL in instead of the Edit/Display form.